# Prevent losing form data by navigating away from page

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am creating a datagrid with hundreds of rows which contain a checkbox on each row so that the user can select an item from the grid.

Now the user may spend a great deal of time going filtering/searching through the grid and ticking the required checkboxes, only to accidentally press the backspace key on their keyboard or click on a hyperlink on the page. And they would lose all their checkbox selections.

So I want to introduce some functionality whereby if at least one checkbox has been ticked, then if the user unintentionally does an action that would navigate them away from the page, then a JavaScript confirm message is displayed to notify the user of this.

The checkboxes would all belong to the same group, for instance it would be called "products".

Is this possible to do at all?

Comment: Have you tried looking at HTML5's LocalStorage?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a `beforeunload` event which occurs when the user navigates away: http://jsfiddle.net/FprNV/1/.

Returning a string there results in a message appearing with two buttons (stay/navigate); the exact implementation of this dialog differs across browsers.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    var checkboxcount = $("input:checkbox:checked").length;
    if(checkboxcount > 0) {
        return 'Are you sure?';
    }
});
```

Comment: Does it also work for leaving the page by posting a different form?

Comment: Is this cross browser compatible? Can browsers disable it? (some pages misuse the feature and are really annoying when you trying to close them...)

Comment: @Tomas Telensky: It works for any leaving, also closing the window etc. I'm not aware of any means of disabling it that the user is able to use. It does work on all major browsers, though. ...except Opera and Safari I now see. And it seems only Chrome actually displays the custom message, IE and Firefox show a generic built-in message.